# A problem with texture atlasing in Unity

Tags: c#, unity, textures, texture-atlas, mesh

I have the texture below and I need to get rectangular parts from it. I could finally combine meshes of different quads to improve performance, but I with quads of different tilings, this means different materials, then combining meshes will fail.

Can anybody tell me how to have a part of that texture in C#? Such that all quads will be of the same material only then combining meshes passes.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This question seems to be incomplete. What API are you using?

Comment: @Andrew Russell actually I'm not that expert. I don't even know if there's any API that does this. But I've been working on a game for about 2 months. It's complete know, and I'm in optimization phase, since it's targeted to mobile phones.

Comment: What I mean is, are you using "XNA" or "Unity" or something like that? Or are you looking for something that works with the .NET framework only (`System.Drawing` perhaps). Although even if you provide that info, I'm not sure your question contains enough information about what you are trying to achieve to give you a good answer. Try expanding it.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Russell, I missed that this is general game development department. I need this in Unity.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting 2D graphics but your question isn't clear about that. Are you doing 2D graphics or is this something for 3D?

Comment: @jhocking it's 2d. But I solved it below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I modified [this code](http://www.jakel168.com/2011/03/unity3d-c-reducing-draw-calls-and.html) to get what I need. I modified it and this is my final code:

```
    Vector2[] uvb;
    Vector2[] uva = new Vector2[] { new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(0, 1) };
    float w, h, left, bottom, posX, posY;
    Rect uv = new Rect();
    MeshFilter filter;

    for (int i=0; i<rects.Count; i++)
    {
        AdaptedRect rect = rects[i];

        w = rect.width * blockWidth;
        h = rect.height * blockHeight;

        left = rect.left * blockWidth;
        bottom = rect.bottom * blockHeight;

        posX = groundRect.left + left + w / 2;
        posY = groundRect.bottom + bottom + h / 2;

        squareBlocksPool[i].transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, squareBlocksPosZ);
        squareBlocksPool[i].transform.localScale = new Vector3(w, h, blockThickness);
        squareBlocksPool[i].SetActive(true);

        // ATLASING
        uv.x = 0;
        uv.y = 0;
        uv.width = rect.width / columns;
        uv.height = rect.height / rows;

        filter = (MeshFilter)squareBlocksPool[i].GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        uvb = new Vector2[uva.Length];

        for (int p = 0; p < uva.Length; p++)
        {
            uvb[p] = new Vector2(uva[p].x * uv.width + uv.x, uva[p].y * uv.height + uv.y);
            filter.mesh.uv = uvb;
        }
    }
```